# InvalidOperationException when Serializing an object with a IXmlSerializable object

Tags: c#, object, serialization, xml-serialization

I've come across some interesting behavior with the XmlSerializer.

If I try to serialize a class that has a property of `Type` object and that object implements `IXmlSerializable`, the serializer will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with the `InnerException`:

The type ConsoleApplication1.MyClass may not be used in this context. To use ConsoleApplication1.MyClass as a parameter, return type, or member of a class or struct, the parameter, return type, or member must be declared as type ConsoleApplication1.MyClass (it cannot be object). Objects of type ConsoleApplication1.MyClass may not be used in un-typed collections, such as ArrayLists.

However, if the object does NOT implement `IXmlSerializable`, the serializer will execute just fine.

Is this a bug in the way that the XmlSerializer is handling objects that are IXmlSerializable?

Below is a very basic case that will cause this exception to throw.

```
public class SerializableClass
{
    public object Configuration { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyProperty = string.Empty;
    }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) { /*Read*/ }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer) { /*Write*/ }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerializableClass element = new SerializableClass
        {
            Configuration = new MyClass
            {
                MyProperty = "My Awesome Property"
            }
        };

        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableClass), new Type[] { typeof(MyClass) });
            serializer.Serialize(writer, element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The one thing I can think of that is causing this problem is that the XmlSerializer preventing me from serializing in this fashion because it won't know Type to call ReadXml on in deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration property in the SerializableClass is causing the problems.  It is declared as an object, changing it to type MyClass will fix your problem

```
public class SerializableClass
{
    public MyClass Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Configuration needs to able to be any object, not just 'MyClass' which is why it is of type object.